# I need some random image spawn in my game but i just don't know now

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to do a scroller type game but I need help with the coins spawning.

This is my code:

```
import os
import pygame


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode(((0, 0)), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption('First game')
image = pygame.image.load('Game_icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(image)

GREEN = (0, 150, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0,)
FPS = 60
FPS_SLOMO = 30
VEL = 5
PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT = 55, 55
COIN_WIDTH, COIN_HEIGHT = 20, 20

PLAYER_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('Assets', 'Player.png'))
PLAYER = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(
    PLAYER_IMAGE, (PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT)), 0)

COIN_IMAGE = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Assets", 'coin.png'))
COIN = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(
    COIN_IMAGE, (COIN_WIDTH, COIN_HEIGHT)), 0)

def draw_window(player, coin):
    WIN.fill(GREEN)
    WIN.blit(PLAYER, (player.x, player.y))
    WIN.blit(COIN, (coin.x, coin.y))
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    player = pygame.Rect(100, 300, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT)
    coin = pygame.Rect(100, 100, COIN_WIDTH, COIN_HEIGHT)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a]:
            player.x -= VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d]:
            player.x += VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w]:
            player.y -= VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s]:
            player.y += VEL
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
            clock.tick(FPS_SLOMO)
        draw_window(player, coin)

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I suggest clarifying, in your question, exactly what you are looking to do, and where in the code. You can probably get away with posting a [mre] rather than your full code, which will help make your post more easy to read and understand. The [tour] and the [ask] page, and the [help/on-topic], have some really helpful information to help improve your post.

Comment: that is all of my code .

Comment: i don't know where to put it and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What isn't working as you would like?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I don't know how to make random images spawn on screen. that's what I'm aiming for right now with this help.

Comment: Do you know how to make non-random images spawn on the screen?

Comment: @sharkanoly I know that's your full code. You must have misread my comment; I specifically said that that was the issue, that your full code is posted, without any specific explanation, rather than just a simplified [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem well, it could be solved like this:

```
import random

NUM_COINS = 100

coins = [[
random.randint(0, WIDTH), random.randint(0, HEIGHT)] for _ in range(NUM_COINS)]

def draw_window(player):
    WIN.fill(GREEN)
    WIN.blit(PLAYER, (player.x, player.y))
    for pos in coins:
        WIN.blit(COIN, (pos[0], pos[1]))
    pygame.display.update()
```

I hope it will help you, Adam.

PS: I would recommend reducing the VEL and increasing the FPS for a better game experience